# session not getting timed out in 5 seconds

Tags: php, html

Hey guys am trying to determine if two minutes are over in php..I have an input box and a php script that checks if 5 seconds are over or not..What i need is when the user inserts the correct value i just want to display  `password is correct` and `you are now logged in with the existing token`.

After 5 seconds i want to display the message like `you cant login with this token id anymore`.

But the problem is everytime am geting the message `you are now logged in with the existing token` after 5 seconds. its not showing up the message `you cant login ...`..

The code i have used..

```
<?php
    session_start();
$_SESSION['logintime'] = time();
$name = $_POST['fname'];
$tokenvalue = 'sample';
if($name != $tokenvalue) {
    echo 'the token is incorrect<br>';
} else {
    echo "the token is correct<br>";
}


if (time() > $_SESSION['logintime'] + 5) {
   echo 'you cant login with this token id anymore<br>';
} else {
echo 'you are now logged in with the existing token';
}
```

Hope can i diplay the message `you cant login with this token id anymore` after 5 seconds ??..

Where am i doing wrong ??..Any help would be apreciated..Thanx

Comment: You are overwriting the `logintime` in the session on each execution. Before overwriting the `$_SESSION['logintime']`, save it locally first to a variable and use this variable in the if statement `(time () > $logintime + 5)`

Comment: @dbf am sorry i didnt get you ..??..so you say i wanna do like `$logintime = $_SESSION['logintime']` ??

Comment: @dbf the suggesion you told me didnt work out

Comment: Re-read the comment from @dbf, you are overwriting the login time in you session variable **before** making the comparison.

Comment: @Mr.Blackus i didnt get what you mean by overwriting ??..can you tell me with an example ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PHP script is executed by the server. As soon as you see something in your browser, there is no action on the server anymore (at least in this script).

To accomplish what you are trying here, you need to use `AJAX` (asynchronous javascript and xml).

There are some things that are eglible in this case:

- Hardcoded request after `x`-seconds with javascript (I would recommend using jQuery for this):

  ```
  setTimeout(function(){$('#message').load('myScript.php');}, 5000);
  ```
- You could use `SSE` (Sever-Sent Events), where you open a persistent connection to the server and push the event after `x`-seconds. There are good tutorials on [HTML5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events).
- You could use only javascript, because the message will only be on the client side - you need to validate the time anyways, before you save a user input. For this you could also use jQuery:

  ```
  setTimeout(function(){$('#message').html('you cant login with this token id anymore<br>');}, 5000);
  ```

**Update:** there are some things strange in your code (I will try to explain what I mean using comments):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // you set the login, before you validate the users input
    $_SESSION['logintime'] = time();
    // thats okay, but actually not really necessary
    $name = $_POST['fname'];
    // thats okay for a test only :)
    $tokenvalue = 'sample';
    if($name != $tokenvalue) {
        // you should use exit() or die() when the login fails to end the script
        echo 'the token is incorrect<br>';
    } else {
        // first you use the word "token" now "password"
        echo "the password is correct<br>";
    }

    if (time() > $_SESSION['logintime'] + 5) {
        echo 'you cant login with this token id anymore<br>';
    } else {
        echo 'you are now logged in with the existing token';
    }
```

**Update2:** Maybe this helps you - it does what you described in the question:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $tokenvalue = 'sample';
            if(isset($_POST['token'])){
                if($_POST['token'] === $tokenvalue) {
                    echo '<div id="success">The password is correct.<br>You are now logged in with the existing token.</div>';
                }
            }
        ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            Token: <input type="text" name="token"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <script>
            if(typeof(document.getElementById('success')) != 'undefined') {
                setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('success').innerHTML = "You can't login with this token anymore."},5000);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @marc..i have tried this with ajax too but it didnt worked out..my ajax file http://pastebin.com/LNWNDd5r..it would be helpful if you can post the code which helps

Comment: I would recommend you to use jQuery. It makes especially things like AJAX so much easier. You can use it over their CDN (or download it and use it locally) `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>` and then you can use the samples from above in a document ready function: `$(function(){ /* code that should be executed as soon as the DOM is loaded */ });`

Comment: am not really good in jquery ..could you provide the jquery code for this action so that i could connect that with my php file and make it work

Comment: For this, I would need further informations. What do you want to do, when you get the response of `check.php`?

Comment: see i just want to display the message `you cant login with this token anymore` after 5 seconds of time ..i know ajax is needed as you told ,,my jquery code as you said me to implement http://pastebin.com/JjRFtx1W..but it doesnt worked out ..please help me

Comment: You need to define an element with the ID `message` because `#message` will look for it. Example: `<div id="message"></div>`

Comment: Oh, you forgot the `<script></script>` tags around the javascript

Comment: i did and the problem remains the same .:(

Comment: My ajax.js file http://pastebin.com/fw2z5G64 , My html input file http://freetexthost.com/ycw0xhl13a...Finally my php file http://pastebin.com/huGsgh8V

Comment: Try out what I updated in my answer (Update2). But you should really try to read into the whole web stuff first - you did a lot of beginners misstakes (what is no problem) :-) There are lots of good coding schools (for free) - just google for one and start from the beginning :)

Comment: what a stupid i am ..:( .i didnt used this simple logic..and thanx for helping me out